# No Drive Activity for Items with primaryActionDetail -> PERMANENT_DELETE

Tags: google-apps-activity

Drive Activity API no longer returns activity for permanently deleted items.

Query json -> "ancestorName": "items/root"

Returns items when they are trashed e.g. primaryActionDetail -> TRASH but no longer returns items that are permanently deleted e.g. primaryActionDetail -> PERMANENT_DELETE

Has this feature been intentionally removed? Has a bug been introduced that has removed it?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, if I query a file that was permanently deleted, I get the expected `"type": "PERMANENT_DELETE"` action. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: using the endpoint https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/query. The json to use as the request body is {"ancestorName": "items/root"}.  This is a request to get all activity, NOT a single item.  We can see the PERMANENT_DELETE on a single item fine.  However, the PERMANENT_DELETE  does not appear when effectively watching all changes using the query provided

Comment: If I request all activity (using `{"ancestorName": "items/root"}`) I can also get `PERMANENT_DELETE` actions, so I cannot reproduce this anyway. Are you sure those actions are not in successive pages of the response?